# Ionic platform.exitApp() not saves localStorage

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

When I'm using `platform.exitApp()` the changes to `localStorage` I did right before execute exit are not saving.

Here is how I initiate it:

```
this.user.profileGetbyId(this.user.userdata.id)
                                .subscribe(res => {
                                    if(res && res.success) {

                                        localStorage.setItem('user', res.data);
                                        this.user.userdata = res.data;
                                        console.log(this.user.userdata);
                                        this.platform.exitApp();

                                        //temp decision
                                        // setTimeout(() => {
                                        //  this.platform.exitApp();
                                        // }, 500);

                                    }
                                })
```

In this way, before `exit()` initiates the console shows me that I have updated the user, but when I start app the next time I have the user that was before `exit()`.

The next thing I tried was to call exit with a time delay, using `setTimeout()`. With this `timeout` the user saves correctly.

How do I keep the changes in right way without `setTimeout()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this.storage.set returns a promise, wait for it to resolve and do
>   exit.

Here's the code

```
this.storage.set('user', res.data).then(data=>{
   this.user.userdata = res.data;
   this.platform.exitApp();
})
```

in localStorage, use JSON.stringify before setting

```
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(res.data));
```

to get the value from localStorage, use

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
```

Comment: how to do it with localStorage, not with @ionic-storage ?

Comment: localStorage doesn't return promise. It can simple like this -> localStorage.set("user", JSON.stringify(res.data)); this.platform.exitApp();

Comment: Can you tell me please, is the @ionic-storage works with localStorage?

Comment: yes, you can, by adding this app.module imports
 IonicStorageModule.forRoot({
      name: '__mydb',
         driverOrder: ['localstorage','indexeddb', 'sqlite', 'websql']
    })

Comment: and may I know why you want to use localStorage via ionic storage?

Comment: I'm working with legacy code, this was not my decision. In this app all data stored in localStorage and I have to work with it... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`this.storage.set()` returns a promise and resolves when key and value are set. (See [Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/))

So you need to call `then` like this:

```
this.storage.set('user', res.data).then(data => { 
    this.user.userdata = res.data;
    this.platform.exitApp();
}
```

Comment: how to do it with localStorage, not with @ionic-storage ?